# Why does glm::mat3 and glm::value_ptr creates a black hole through time and universe and is destroying any possible logic in my mind?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I was creating a beautiful graphic engine with the all so famous OpenGL framework but then an unexpected problem came to me (like every problems do).

I had to create a function that modifies a specific value in a glm::mat3. to do so I created a simple function that return me a simple reference to a specific float in a glm::mat3 but nothing seems to work for I don't know which reason.

Here is my function:

```
float& mat3ValueAt(glm::mat3& m, int l, int c) {
    // l is the line index and c is the column index...
    return glm::value_ptr(m)[3 * l + c];
}
```

To see if it worked, I had to use a function that was able to display my matrix:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, glm::mat3 m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        stream << GLS::mat3ValueAt(m, i / 3, i % 3) << ((i + 1) % 3 ? ' ' : '\n');
    }
    return stream;
}
```

All of this DIDN'T work... but that's ok... it must be my bad... so I reduced my not-working code that seems good to the smallest code in which I could find an anomalie...

And here is what I ended up being totally mad about and it turned me insane:

```
int main() {
    glm::mat3 m;
    std::cout << "display uninitialised value..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(glm::value_ptr(m) + 5) << std::endl; // should display an uninitialised value
    *(glm::value_ptr(m) + 5) = 42;
    std::cout << "display the initialised value" << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(glm::value_ptr(m) + 5) << std::endl; // should display 42
}
```

and the result of this small code is...

```
display uninitialised value...
42
display the initialised value
42
```

So the fact that my two previous functions aren't working is ok, maybe I just don't know how value_ptr works... but I'm pretty sure of one thing...
A value CAN'T have the value that we're gonna assign it BEFORE it was assigned to it!

And it doesn't matter the value I put instead of 42, it will always be assign before I assign it!

How is this possible?

Comment: "A value CAN'T have the value that we're gonna assign it BEFORE it was assigned to it !" -> Uninitialized variable can have any value, including 42. And compiler might even optimize `*(glm::value_ptr(m) + 5) = 42;` to do it right on initialization. But more likely, your function stack is created in the same place in memory in constructive calls to your program, so value 42 is reused.

Comment: To follow up on @R2RT's comment, on my machine I can do the same thing with `int m[4]` and print the value of `m[2]` before and after an assignment `m[2] = 42`. Compiling with `-O3` it prints out 42 twice. Compiling without optimization it prints out 0 then 42. (this is with clang on osx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

> ```
> glm::mat3 m;
> ```

Creates an uninitialized object; the contents of this object have indeterminate values. Any attempt to read the value of an object with indeterminate values leads to undefined behavior.

Because of that, the compiler is free to re-order your code to look like this:

```
int main() {
    glm::mat3 m;
    *(glm::value_ptr(m) + 5) = 42;
    std::cout << "display uninitialised value..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(glm::value_ptr(m) + 5) << std::endl; // should display an uninitialised value
    std::cout << "display the initialised value" << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(glm::value_ptr(m) + 5) << std::endl; // should display 42
}
```

This is perfectly valid because if you tried to read from the value before initializing it, you're in undefined behavior land, and having that value already be initialized is no more correct than any other undefined behavior.